# Transform a 3 columns (x, y, result) Python Pandas DataFrame to a DataFrame of result values with x (unique) as row and y (unique) as column

Tags: python, numpy, pandas, dataframe

I would like to transform a Python Pandas DataFrame `df` like:

```
      x  y  result
id                
1  -0.8 -1    0.64
2  -0.8  0   -0.36
3  -0.4 -1    0.16
4  -0.4  0   -0.84
5   0.0 -1    0.00
6   0.0  0   -1.00
7   0.4 -1    0.16
8   0.4  0   -0.84
9   0.8 -1    0.64
10  0.8  0   -0.36
```

to a DataFrame like this:

```
        -1     0
-0.8  0.64 -0.36
-0.4  0.16 -0.84
 0.0     0 -1.00
 0.4  0.16 -0.84
 0.8  0.64 -0.36
```

I know how to get unique x values:

```
df["x"].unique()
```

and unique y values with:

```
df["y"].unique()
```

but I don't know how to "distribute" `result` column values inside DataFrame.

I would prefer a vectorized solution in order to avoid for loops.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is a *pivot* operation, you can either use [`.pivot_table`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.pivot_table.html#pandas.pivot_table):

```
>>> df.pivot_table(values='result', index='x', columns='y')
y       -1     0
x               
-0.8  0.64 -0.36
-0.4  0.16 -0.84
 0.0  0.00 -1.00
 0.4  0.16 -0.84
 0.8  0.64 -0.36
```

or [`.pivot`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html#pandas.DataFrame.pivot):

```
>>> df.pivot(index='x', columns='y')['result']
y       -1     0
x               
-0.8  0.64 -0.36
-0.4  0.16 -0.84
 0.0  0.00 -1.00
 0.4  0.16 -0.84
 0.8  0.64 -0.36
```

or [`.groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html#pandas.DataFrame.groupby) followed by [`.unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html#pandas.DataFrame.unstack):

```
>>> df.groupby(['x', 'y'])['result'].aggregate('first').unstack()
y       -1     0
x               
-0.8  0.64 -0.36
-0.4  0.16 -0.84
 0.0  0.00 -1.00
 0.4  0.16 -0.84
 0.8  0.64 -0.36
```

Comment: Wow! thanks a lot! what is the difference between `pivot` and `pivot_table`?

Comment: @FemtoTrader see the API links for details

Comment: ok I will see API links. Even if it's longer I like your groupby solution because it helped me to understand groupby, aggregate and unstack methods.